# Для чего здесь нужен typedef? Что делают эти прототипы?

Tags: c++, c, функции, типы-данных, typedef

Лазил я по коду imgui, и нашел там такой код:

```
typedef int     (*ImGuiInputTextCallback)(ImGuiInputTextCallbackData* data);
typedef void    (*ImGuiSizeCallback)(ImGuiSizeCallbackData* data); 
typedef void*   (*ImGuiMemAllocFunc)(size_t sz, void* user_data);   
typedef void    (*ImGuiMemFreeFunc)(void* ptr, void* user_data);
```

Для чего здесь нужен typedef? Что вообще делают эти прототипы?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Объявление

```
typedef int     (*ImGuiInputTextCallback)(ImGuiInputTextCallbackData* data);
```

объявляет `ImGuiInputTextCallback` как тип указателя на функцию, которая принимает указатель `ImGuiInputTextCallbackData*` и возвращает `int`.

Ну, все остальные — рассматриваются аналогично...

```
int MyCallback1(ImGuiInputTextCallbackData* data) { return 1; };
int MyCallback2(ImGuiInputTextCallbackData* data) { return 2; };
int MyCallback3(ImGuiInputTextCallbackData* data) { return 3; };
....
ImGuiInputTextCallback f;
f = MyCallback2;
f(NULL);
```

Без `typedef` это было бы объявление *переменной, а не типа* и выглядело примерно так:

```
int MyCallback1(ImGuiInputTextCallbackData* data) { return 1; };
int MyCallback2(ImGuiInputTextCallbackData* data) { return 2; };
int MyCallback3(ImGuiInputTextCallbackData* data) { return 3; };
....
int (*f)(ImGuiInputTextCallbackData* data);
f = MyCallback2;
f(NULL);
```

Comment: А нельзя просто указать `int     (*ImGuiInputTextCallback)(ImGuiInputTextCallbackData* data);` почему именно **typedef**?

Comment: @Y0MMY чтобы потом получить тип `ImGuiInputTextCallback` для дальнейшей работы с ним. То есть для получения указателя на функции в параметры нужно будет написать `ImGuiInputTextCallback func`, а не `int     (*func)(ImGuiInputTextCallbackData* data)`.  `typedef` позволяет добавить название - синоним к типу, что можно использовать для упрощения кода.

Comment: @V31R То есть, грубо говоря, благодаря typedef мы "создаем новый тип данных"?

Comment: Скорее, *псевдоним*.